# sorting lists by score and keeping pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, sorting, pagination

I have three unordered lists with list items inside, each containing a score from 1 to 10. I have pagination, so I have three identical ul items in the page.

I need a button that when clicked, orders the list items by descending number (so from 10 to 1).

the html is:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="first active">1</li>
    <li class="second">2</li>
    <li class="third">3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sort">
    <li class="sortEm">sort by score</li>
</ul>
<div class="block" style="display:block">
    <ul class="reviews_list">
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">10</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">7</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">9</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">2</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">2</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <ul class="reviews_list">
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">1</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">2</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">3</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">7</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">9</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <ul class="reviews_list">
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">10</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">2</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">2</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">1</div>
        </li>
        <li class="one_review">score:
            <div class="score">5</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the js is

```
$(".pagination li").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(".block").hide();
    $(".block").eq($(this).index()).show()
});


$(".sortEm").click(function () {




    function sortEm(a, b) {
        return parseInt($(".score", a).text()) < parseInt($(".score", b).text()) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    $("li.one_review").sort(sortEm).prependTo($(".reviews_list"));


});
```

the problem is that using this function, when i click the button, i lose the pagination. here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ed03xy9/2/

How do I write the javascript in order for it to move the li items from block to block, maintain the pagination and display them from 10 to 1? I'm not a js expert, so this is something I have no idea how to do. I came this far for now.. can anyone help? thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the code that insert sorted list to

```
//store sorted list in variable so we can iterate over it and divide it
//this list combine all '.one_review' (li)s in the 3 reviews_list (ul)s
var sortedList = $("li.one_review").sort(sortEm);

// i iteration variable to let us know where we are in sortedList iteration
// we will increase it every iteration throgh sortedList elements
var i = 0;

// j iteration variable to point to Nth of ul.reviews_list (we have 3 ul.reviews_list)
// we will increase it when i=0, i=5 and i=10 
var j = -1;

// the number of items per page (here the sortedList length is 15 and we wanna dived it to 3 pages )
// 15/3 = 5 then round it
var itemsPerPage = Math.round(sortedList.length / 3);

// iterate over each item in sortedList array 
// https://api.jquery.com/each/ 
sortedList.each(function(){

    //if reminder of Nth of element / itemsPerPage equal zero that mean
    //we need to move to next ul.reviews_list empty it.
    if( i % itemsPerPage == 0 ){
        //move to next ul.reviews_list
        // we will enter here 3 times:
        // in first iteration when i=0 then 0%5 = 0 then j will be 0
        // in 6th iteration when i=5 then 5%5 = 0 then j will be 1
        // in 11th iteration when i=10 then 10%5 = 0 then j will be 2
        ++j;

        // empty current ul.reviews_list
        // see : https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/
        // see : http://api.jquery.com/html/
        $('.reviews_list:eq('+j+')').html("");
    }

    // append current li.one_review(this) to current ul.reviews_list (:eq(j))
    $('.reviews_list:eq('+j+')').append(this);

    ++i;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ed03xy9/5/

Comment: works perfectly :) could you integrate your answer with an explanation of what this does exactly? that would be awesome

Comment: no problem, but i hardly write English so I hope my explanation in `comments ` above is clear to you